# ASP.NET MVC 5 site - edit view not selecting item in DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC 5 site...

A story can be optionally associated with a PlaceId. A blank placeId is also valid. A place can be associated with more than one story.

**Models**

```
public class Place
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string PlaceName { get; set; }
}   

public class Story
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid? PlaceId { get; set; }
    public string StoryName { get; set; }
}
```

I have several requirements.

- When editing the story I would like a drop down list of all places to
  be displayed - with the associated place (if any) - selected.
- I want to use the strongly typed DropDownListFOR (as opposed to 
  DropDownList).
- I want to add a "No Associated Place" which will be
  selected if PlaceId is null (and should pass null back to the model).
- I want to add a css class = "form-control" to the DropDownListFor.

**Controller (Get)**

```
public ActionResult Edit(Guid Id)
{
    // Get Story
    var story = StoryRepo.SelectArticle(Id);

    // Put select list of all places in ViewBag
    ViewBag.PlaceId = new SelectList(PlaceRepo.SelectAll(), "Id", "PlaceName", new { Id = story.PlaceId });

    // Return view
    return View(story);
}
```

**In View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PlaceId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.PlaceId, "No Associated Place",
                                    new { @class = "form-control" })
```

This populates the dropdown list fine, and when you select an item the PlaceId is in the model bound to the controller. However - it does not select the existing PlaceId when the view loads.

Shouldn't the final parameter in the ViewBag.PlaceId line `new { Id = story.PlaceId }` - cause this selection?

I can't find anything on this specific issue online - and can find little about how to bind a dropdown to a strongly typed edit view in the way I require.

How can I make it select the correct item? (also any improvements on how I am doing this also appreciated).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change the following code

```
   // Put select list of all places in ViewBag
    ViewBag.PlaceId = new SelectList(PlaceRepo.SelectAll(), "Id",
                             "PlaceName", new { Id = story.PlaceId });
```

to become

```
   // Put select list of all places in ViewBag
    ViewBag.PlaceId = new SelectList(PlaceRepo.SelectAll(), "Id", 
                             "PlaceName", story.PlaceId);
```

Definition of the SelectedList from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx)

> SelectList(IEnumerable, String, String, Object): Initializes a new
>   instance of the SelectList class by using the specified items for the
>   list, the data value field, the data text field, and a selected value.

here a working [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PIGNLF)

updated [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NbEydc)

Hope this will help you

Comment: also you have something in the view

Comment: I am wondering if in the way that you wrote the dropdownlistfor, the place holder is working with you?

Comment: I am not attached to this way of doing things - open to a better way.

Comment: I built a small demo on dotnetfiddle,you can check the demo, the only changes you need to do in your code , is to set the value in the controller directly without passing it as anonymous, and i confirmed that the place holder is working also

Comment: thanks - your example seems to be missing the one to many relationship between the models though?

Comment: the id in class Sample will represent the foreign key PlaceId, I coded it in this way just for easy, i can modify it to add more details

Comment: sorry either this doesnt help me - or I don't really understand what you are recommending.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123651/discussion-between-hadi-hassan-and-niico).